# ubuntu 12.04.3 : gcc 4.8.2 in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ubuntu, gcc

I use source-compiled (--enable-language=c,c++,objc,obj-c++) gcc-4.8.2 in ubuntu.12.04.3.

I write this test code.

```
#import <objc/Object.h>

#include <stdio.h>

@interface Number : Object
{
@public
    int number;
}

- (void)printNum;

@end

@implementation Number : Object

- (void)printNum
{
    printf("%d\n", number);
}

@end

int main()
{
    Number *num = [[Number alloc] init];
    num->number = 7;
    [num printNum];
    return 0;
}
```

but I received the following error:

```
test.m: In function ‘main’:
test.m:26:2: warning: ‘Number’ may not respond to ‘+alloc’ [enabled by default]
  Number *num = [[Number alloc] init];
  ^
test.m:26:2: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature [enabled by default]
test.m:26:2: warning: will be assumed to return ‘id’ and accept [enabled by default]
test.m:26:2: warning: ‘...’ as arguments.) [enabled by default]
test.m:26:2: warning: no ‘-init’ method found [enabled by default]
```

Why do these warning occur?

and, I try to install libobjc 4.8.2, but I couldn't find the source. So I do "`sudo apt-get install gobjc`". and "`sudo apt-get install libobjc4`". But when the program starts, It occurs *segmentation fault*;

Where can I download the source of libobjc (and another required runtime library)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Object` class is obsolete, and doesn't implement the `alloc` method, hence the error message.

Use `NSObject` instead. You will have to include the proper framework, which is Foundation.